# Как вывести функцию php в ответе json?

Tags: php, json

**page.php--**

```
        $ss = get_stock($id);

        $success = [
            'ok' => $ss
        ];

        echo json_encode($success); 
        exit();
```

**ajax --**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'page.php',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            product_id : id,
        },
        success: function(data) {
             //тут нужно вывести `ok` из page.php
        }
```

На страницу page.php выполняется ajax запрос после чего нужно вывести, то что вернуло функция **get_stock($id);**

Так как я сделал - не работает, но если переменную $ss заменить на $ss = 'sometext'; то все сообщение выводиться.

функция get_stock возвращает (на самом деле не это, но сути это не меняет)

```
function get_stock($id) {
?>
 <div class="<?php echo $id ?>"></div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: а что возвращает `get_stock` ?

Comment: @СергейМишин , 
если вкратце, то что-то такое 
получает id и выводит html

`function get_stock($id) {
 ?>
 <div id="<?php echo $id; ?>">ss</div>
 <?php
}`

Comment: `функция get_stock возвращает ((на самом деле не это)` -- на самом деле она ничего не возвращает. синтаксис некорректный

Comment: @СергейМишин 
вот такой ответ приходит, но  alert(data['ok']);  ничего не выводит 
скрин: https://hsto.org/webt/5e/b5/2b/5eb52bb410555083481696.png

Comment: `function get_stock($id) {

 return '<div class="'. $id .'"></div>';

}`

Comment: @СергейМишин , Спасибо вам за помощь, get_stock действительно ничего не возвращал. Решил следующим образом: В начале функции get_stock нужно включить буферизацию, в конце функции получить буфер и вернуть его

`<?php
function get_stock($id) {
  ob_start();
?>
...тут html

<?php
    $result = ob_get_clean();
 
    return $result;
}
?>`.

В целом вариант @splash58 рабочий, но не в этом случае, скорее из-за плохой архитектуры моего кода.